# What i should do? Calculate in the client and have more requests or calculate on the server and have fewer requests

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular, express, http

For **example**, I'm doing a shopping cart and i want to save idClient, createdAt, total and products in the purchase, and in each purchase discount the amount of the products.

the database would look like this:

Ticket table: **| idClient | createdAt | total |**

Products table: **| name | price | amount |**

ProductsInTicket table: **| idTicket | idProduct | amount |**

So i have two options at each end:

1. **Client**: calculate the total and send a request for save the ticket then send a request for save each productInTicket and discount the amount.

   **Server**: Just get the requests and save it.

Example requests in json:

```json
// Request 1:
{
    "idClient": 1,
    "createdAt": "2020-01-01",
    "total": 200
}
// example response: { id: 1 }

// Request 2 (For each productInTicket):
{
    idTicket: 1,
    idProduct: 1,
    amount: 2
}
```

2. **Client**: send the ticket and the products in one request.

   **Server**: calculate the total and save the ticket then save each productInTicket and discount the amount of each product.

Example request in json:

```json
// Just one request:
{
    "idClient": 1,
    "createdAt": "2020-01-01",
    "total": 200, // 200 because product price is 100 x 2 of amount is 200
    "products": [
        {
            idProduct: 1,
            amount: 2
        }
    ]
}
```

Which option should I choose?, I have to take one extreme or the other, or do I have to be in balance? In the last case help me with a example please. This is just an example, in a biggest app should i have to choose the same option?.

I use angular in the client side, node.js with express in the server side and in this case mysql as database, in case it is necessary.

**< Edit >**

I know the logic should be in the backend, but this is going to waste a lot of resources (Or i'm wrong?), in the other hand, if i do the logic in the frontend **(without showing any type of private or sensitive information)** i don't have to use some much resources in my server side. So without personal tastes, What is better? Think about not spending resources on the server at the cost of many requests, or spending resources on it but having few requests. Is there any research on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always aim to have the logic side of the app at the backend, simply because it's your business logic there it's where it belongs. Not just for a matter of security but to maintain the front-end clean. The client-side should be dumb as possible, receive data and display, backend should be doing the heavy lifting.